# How to append observable arrays to form a single stream of data

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my angular app, I came-across a scenario where I need to initialize an empty Observable array of custom type and append new observable arrays in a loop to form single stream of custom objects (using flatMap). How do I do it?

Comment: Can you share some code of what you have done so far?

Comment: Adding from @OliverCooke, could you also give us the final structure of your goal ? It isn't really clear to me

Comment: I'll post my code